# What is the API usage (requests per seconds) limit of Amadeus test environment?

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to call Amadeus API in parallel (`/v1/shopping/hotel-offers`) in the **test environment**. Unfortunately when I start 3 threads simultaneously, then only the very first one gets the OK response and the others get `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` responses.

I have not exceeded the monthly limit quota yet, so that error is really related to the parallel execution.

Does anybody know what are the exact limits (#requests/sec or #requests in parallel) ? Is it even possible to have more than one request at a time ?

Answer (score 1):

The throttling is not the same depending of the environment:

**Test**: 10 transactions per sec per user (10 TPS/user) -> With the constrains: not more than 1 request every 100ms.

**Production**: 20 transactions per sec per user (20 TPS/user) -> With the constraint: not more than 1 request every 50ms.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Is there any way to increase this TPS? I mean by paying more? Or may be switching to Entreprise API enable more TPS?

Comment: Hi, I just replied to your other question. Please contact us at developers@amadeus.com so we can better understand you need and see what we can do to help you.